# Is async/await suitable for methods that are both IO and CPU bound?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

The MSDN documentation appears to state that `async` and `await` are suitable for IO-bound tasks whereas `Task.Run` should be used for CPU-bound tasks.

I'm working on an application that performs HTTP requests to retrieve HTML documents, which it then parses. I have a method that looks like this:

```
public async Task<HtmlDocument> LoadPage(Uri address)
{
    using (var httpResponse = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(address)) //IO-bound
    using (var responseContent = httpResponse.Content)
    using (var contentStream = await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        return await Task.Run(() => LoadHtmlDocument(contentStream)); //CPU-bound
}
```

Is this good and suitable use of `async` and `await`, or am I over-using it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are two good answers already, but to add my 0.02...

If you're talking about *consuming* asynchronous operations, `async`/`await` works excellently for both I/O-bound and CPU-bound.

I think the MSDN docs do have a slight slant towards *producing* asynchronous operations, in which case you do want to use `TaskCompletionSource` (or similar) for I/O-bound and `Task.Run` (or similar) for CPU-bound. Once you've created the initial `Task` wrapper, it's best *consumed* by `async` and `await`.

For your particular example, it really comes down to how much time `LoadHtmlDocument` will take. If you remove the `Task.Run`, you will execute it within the same context that calls `LoadPage` (possibly on a UI thread). The Windows 8 guidelines specify that any operation taking more than 50ms should be made `async`... keeping in mind that 50ms on your developer machine may be longer on a client's machine...

So if you can guarantee that `LoadHtmlDocument` will run for less than 50ms, you can just execute it directly:

```
public async Task<HtmlDocument> LoadPage(Uri address)
{
  using (var httpResponse = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(address)) //IO-bound
  using (var responseContent = httpResponse.Content)
  using (var contentStream = await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()) //IO-bound
    return LoadHtmlDocument(contentStream); //CPU-bound
}
```

However, I would recommend `ConfigureAwait` as @svick mentioned:

```
public async Task<HtmlDocument> LoadPage(Uri address)
{
  using (var httpResponse = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(address)
      .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)) //IO-bound
  using (var responseContent = httpResponse.Content)
  using (var contentStream = await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()
      .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)) //IO-bound
    return LoadHtmlDocument(contentStream); //CPU-bound
}
```

With `ConfigureAwait`, if the HTTP request doesn't complete immediately (synchronously), then this will (in this case) cause `LoadHtmlDocument` to be executed on a thread pool thread without an explicit call to `Task.Run`.

If you're interested in `async` performance at this level, you should check out Stephen Toub's [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T) and [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) on the subject. He has tons of useful information.

Comment: Thought `ConfigureAwait(false)` would mean that the Task should not resume on the context it was started from, when it finishes. Not what thread does the work of the task.

Comment: @mmcrae: Your understanding is correct. When `LoadPage` resumes, it runs on a thread pool thread, and then executes `LoadHtmlDocument` (while on that thread pool thread).

Comment: I think it is good to note that in the above examples ```LoadHtmlDocument``` is still essentially blocking and not offloaded in anyway.

Comment: @davidcarr - according to the answer, that is only true under certain circumstances: *"With ConfigureAwait, **if the HTTP request doesn't complete immediately (synchronously),** then this will (in this case) cause LoadHtmlDocument to be executed on a thread pool thread ..."* But I agree that, to be sure it is always off UI thread, should use `await Task.Run` on `LoadHtmlDocument` call.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve does it mean even with `ConfigureAwait(false)`, if it completes synchronously(you never know), `LoadHtmlDocument` would still be executed on the UI thread? And if `LoadHtmlDocument ` blocks, the UI then freeze?

Comment: @joe: Yes. If the task is already completed, then `ConfigureAwait(false)` has no effect.

Answer (score 21):

It is appropriate to `await` any operation that is asynchronous (i.e. is represented by a `Task`).

The key point is that for IO operations, whenever possible, you want to use a provided method that is, at it's very core, asynchronous, rather than using `Task.Run` on a blocking synchronous method.  If you're blocking a thread (even a thread pool thread) while performing IO, you're not leveraging the real power of the `await` model.

Once you have created a `Task` that represents your operation you no longer care if it's CPU or IO bound.  To the caller it's just some async operation that needs to be `await`-ed.

Answer (score 20):

There are several things to consider:

- In a GUI application, you want as little code as possible to execute on the UI thread. In that case, offloading CPU-bound operation to another thread using `Task.Run()` is probably a good idea. Though the users of your code can do that themselves, if they want.
- In something like ASP.NET application, there is no UI thread and all you care about is performance. In that case, there is some overhead in using `Task.Run()` instead of running the code directly, but it shouldn't be significant if the operation actually takes some time. (Also, there is some overhead in returning to the synchronization context, which is one more reason why you should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for most `await`s in your library code.)
- If your method is async (which BTW should be also reflected in the name of the method, not just its return type), people will expect that it won't block the synchronization context thread, even for CPU-bound work.

Weighting that, I think using `await Task.Run()` is the right choice here. It does have some overhead, but also some advantages, which can be significant.