# Why do i need to use ConfigureAwait(false) in all of transitive closure?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I am learning async/await and after I read this article [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

and this [Is async/await suitable for methods that are both IO and CPU bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896856/is-async-await-suitable-for-methods-that-are-both-io-and-cpu-bound)

I notice one Tip from @Stephen Cleary 's article.

> Using ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlocks is a dangerous practice. You would have to use ConfigureAwait(false) for every await in the transitive closure of all methods called by the blocking code, including all third- and second-party code. Using ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlock is at best just a hack).

It appeared again in the code of the post as I have attached above.

```
public async Task<HtmlDocument> LoadPage(Uri address)
{
    using (var httpResponse = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(address)
        .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)) //IO-bound
    using (var responseContent = httpResponse.Content)
    using (var contentStream = await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)) //IO-bound
        return LoadHtmlDocument(contentStream); //CPU-bound
}
```

As my knowledge when we using ConfigureAwait(false)  the rest of async method will be run in the thread pool. Why we need to add it into every await 
in transitive closure? I myself just think this is the correct version as what I knew.

```
public async Task<HtmlDocument> LoadPage(Uri address)
{
    using (var httpResponse = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(address)
        .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)) //IO-bound
    using (var responseContent = httpResponse.Content)
    using (var contentStream = await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()) //IO-bound
        return LoadHtmlDocument(contentStream); //CPU-bound
}
```

It means the second use of ConfigureAwait(false) in using block is useless. Please tell me the correct way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> As my knowledge when we using `ConfigureAwait(false)` the rest of async method will be run in the thread pool.

Close, but there is an important caveat you are missing.  When you resume after awaiting a task with `ConfigureAwait(false)`, you will resume on an arbitrary thread.  Take note of the words *"when you resume."*

Let me show you something:

```cs
public async Task<string> GetValueAsync()
{
    return "Cached Value";
}

public async Task Example1()
{
    await this.GetValueAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Consider the `await` in `Example1`.  Although you are awaiting an `async` method, that method does not actually perform any asynchronous work.  If an `async` method doesn't `await` anything, it executes synchronously, and the awaiter never *resumes* because it never *suspended* in the first place.  As this example shows, calls to `ConfigureAwait(false)` may be superfluous: they may have no effect at all.  In this example, whatever context you were on when you enter `Example1` is the context you will be on after the `await`.

Not quite what you expected, right?  And yet, it's not altogether unusual.  Many `async` methods may contain fast paths that don't require the caller to suspend.  The availability of a cached resource is a good example (thanks, @jakub-dąbek!), but there plenty of other reasons an `async` method might bail early.  We often check for various conditions at the beginning of a method to see if we can avoid doing unnecessary work, and `async` methods are no different.

Let's look at another example, this time from a WPF application:

```
async Task DoSomethingBenignAsync()
{
    await Task.Yield();
}

Task DoSomethingUnexpectedAsync()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Action(() => tcs.SetResult("Done!")));
    return tcs.Task;
}

async Task Example2()
{
    await DoSomethingBenignAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    await DoSomethingUnexpectedAsync();
}
```

Take a look at `Example2`.  The first method we `await` *always* runs asynchronously.  By the time we hit the second `await`, we know we're running on a thread pool thread, so there's no need for `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the second call, right?  *Wrong.*  Despite having `Async` in the name and returning a `Task`, our second method wasn't written using `async` and `await`.  Instead, it performs its own scheduling and uses a `TaskCompletionSource` to communicate the result.  When you resume from your `await`, you might<sup>[1]</sup> end up running on whatever thread provided the result, which in this case is WPF's dispatcher thread.  Whoops.

The key takeaway here is that you often don't know *exactly* what an 'awaitable' method does.  With *or* without `ConfigureAwait`, you might end up running somewhere unexpected.  This can happen at any level of an `async` call stack, so the surest way to avoid inadvertently taking ownership of a single-threaded context is to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` with *every* `await`, i.e., throughout the transitive closure.

Of course, there may be times when you *want* to resume on your current context, and that's fine.  That is ostensibly why it's the default behavior.  But if you don't *genuinely* need it, then I recommend using `ConfigureAwait(false)` by default. This is especially true for library code.  Library code can get called from anywhere, so it's best adhere to the principle of least surprise.  That means not locking other threads out of your caller's context when you don't need it.  Even if you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everywhere in your library code, your caller will still have the option to resume on *their* original context if that's what they want.

<sub><sup>[1]</sup> This behavior may vary by framework and compiler version.</sub>

Comment: Also there is a possibility that the call returns synchronously with the data (maybe it was cached). In that situation the `ConfigureAwait` doesn't do anything and subsequent calls have to use it

Comment: @JakubDąbek Leave it to me to omit the single most obvious reason ;).  Thank you.

Comment: After I read your answer carefully and seriously, now I better understand about the behavior of `async/await ConfigureAwait`. I just want to leave this link which I also read carefully again after received your answer [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). In the link have the section **Figure 6 Handling a Returned Task that Completes Before It’s Awaited** which mentioned same as what you said. Thanks.

Comment: What if we at Example1 make `return await Task.FromResult("Cached Value");` does it make it async? There is an await, but no task started?

Comment: @Roar No, it does not.  The `Task<>` cooked up by `Task.FromResult` is already in a completed state.  With the result already available, its `await` will complete synchronously, as will the `await` in above it in `Example1`.

Comment: One wonders, when it seems that the best practice advice is to pepper everything with ConfigureAwait(false), that that is not the default behavior?

Comment: Would `ConfigureAwait(false)` on `DoSomethingUnexpectedAsync()` really solve the problem in this case? When we hit the second await, we are sure to be on a thread pool thread, so the SyncCtx is null. There is no difference in using `ConfigureAwait(false)` or not in this case, is it?