# Why does CPU-Bound code lock GUI in async \ await unlike IO-Bound?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

According to Microsoft Article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/hh191443(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#async-methods-are-easier-to-write), It's better to use Threading for CPU-Bound tasks and Async\Await for IO-Bound. On the other hands, some post like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896856/is-async-await-suitable-for-methods-that-are-both-io-and-cpu-bound) says: *If you're talking about consuming asynchronous operations, async/await works excellently for both I/O-bound and CPU-bound.*
I know that Async\Await just uses the current context(single current Thread) and when an encounter with the time-consuming command, it returns control to man caller until the answer arrives.

With the above information, I have tried to test Sync\Await in a DotNet Windows application with the following code:

```
class SampleClass
{
    public  async Task<double> TestAsync()
    {
         HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        Task<double> doIt =  DoWork();

        double result = await doIt;

        return result;  
    }

     private async Task<double> DoWork()
    {
        //Line24: It takes a 4-sec CPU-Bound task and locks GUI when running
        TimeConsumingCPUBound();

        //Line27: It takes a 10-sec IO-Bound task and doesn't lock GUI when running
        await Task.Delay(10000);

        return 0;
    }

    public void TimeConsumingCPUBound()
    {
        string x = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        {
            x = x + i.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

and here I call The code inside a bottom handler:

```
 private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SampleClass d = new SampleClass();
        await d.TestAsync();

    }
```

**My question is Why is in line24(CPU-Bound) GUI is locked But in line27(IO-Bound) isn't it?**
I expected that in both of them GUI would be free!

Comment: *"I know that Async\Await just uses the current context (single current Thread) and when an encounter with the time-consuming command, it returns control to main caller until the answer arrives."* <== What you know is wrong IMHO. Whether the command is time-consuming or not is irrelevant. What is relevant is whether the command is an awaited incomplete asynchronous operation or not.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I told this according this article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/hh191443(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#threads) which says The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async method doesn't run on its own thread

Comment: Mohammad this quote from the docs is correct, but how does it validate your statement about *"the time-consuming command"*? "Time-consuming" does not imply "asynchronous" IMHO. A synchronous, blocking, operation can be time-consuming too.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes I agree with you, By the way, what did you mean by "awaited incomplete asynchronous operation"?

Comment: I mean `Task`s or other awaitables (like `ValueTask`s for example), that have their `IsCompleted` property equals to `false` at the time you `await` them. This is what causes the async state machine to box the continuation and return the control to the caller. Otherwise (if the task is completed) the method does not return, and instead continues running until the next `await`, or until the end of the method.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks friend for your great clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Asynchronous methods begin executing synchronously](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

As noted in [the article you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/hh191443(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#async-methods-are-easier-to-write), "You can use Task.Run to move CPU-bound work to a background thread":

```
private async Task<double> DoWork()
{
  await Task.Run(() => TimeConsumingCPUBound());

  await Task.Delay(10000);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But why my question seems bad?

Comment: Thanks, Task. Run make a new thread? isn't it? can I conclude Async (without Task? Run, Just work in IO-bound that have a IO-delay? I am going to read your nice article

Comment: @Mohammad: `Task.Run` queues work to the thread pool, so its delegate will be run on a thread pool thread.

Comment: Yeah, I meant it uses a new threat rather than the current context thread.

Comment: My problem is about async/await capability. Is it correct to say it just works fine for IO-Bound to return control to the caller? On the other hand, it cannot return the controller in the CPU-Bound process!?

Comment: @Mohammad: `await` will return to the caller if its task isn't complete. In your example, `DoWork` does the CPU-bound work *before* returning the task.